# How do I get the text of a comment that was deleted by a mod?

Tags: support, moderation, comments

I wrote a comment yesterday to [somebody else's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/298673/118852). Today all comments for that answer were deleted by a moderator ("Comments removed as they were getting noisy").

Can I somehow get at the text of my comment? It took me quite a while to write it, and I'm pondering whether it's useful to turn it into a standalone answer. But I don't have my comment draft file any more, and I also don't see the comment in my "all actions" timeline.

How do I get at the text of this deleted comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comment was:

> An important reason why you should distinguish between C and C++ is that the underlying ideas of the languages are quite different nowadays. C++ has a focus on OO and uses RAII as memory management pattern; C has a focus on procedural programming, and I'm not sure what the memory management pattern in C is actually called. While the syntax may be very similar, using these two languages requires very different approaches to program design, so they should not be conflated.